# Reusing code in overloaded constructors

Tags: java, oop, constructor

My `BigBlock` class needs a few overloaded constructors. All of them need to initialize  the same few fields in the same way.

What is the proper way to do this? Is it to make a function, e.g. `Initialize` in the example below, that does these things, and have all constructors call that function?

```
public class BigBlock {
    private Thing parentThing;
    Units lengthUnit;
    LabCoordinateSystem labCoordinateSystem;

    private void Initialize(){
        lengthUnit = parentThing.getPreferredUnits(0);
        labCoordinateSystem = parentThing.getCoordinateSystem();
    }

    BigBlock(Thing myThing){
        parentThing= myThing;
        Initialize();
    }

    BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z){
        parentThing= myThing;
        Initialize();
        // more code involving x, y, z
    }

    // a few more constructors

}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Typically it's best to make all constructors chain to a single one which contains the most information, e.g.

```
BigBlock(Thing myThing) {
    this(myThing, 0, 0, 0); // Assuming 0 is the default value for x, y and z
}
```

It becomes slightly weirder if there are different ways to call the constructor which *don't* effectively represent subsets of the same information - but at that point I'd say there's a design smell anyway.

Note that by the time you've got all the real logic in a single constructor, you don't need your `Initialize` method (which should be `initialize` to follow Java naming conventions, btw) at all - which may *also* you can make fields final which previously you couldn't have done.

Comment: Interesting. Why not do it the other way? Intuitively, I would have called the general constructor from the specific constructor i.e. `BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z){ this(myThing); // etc }` and that's what two other answers suggest. But you may have a reason for preferring it this way round?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: It puts *all* the initialization logic in one place. Also bear in mind that you can't chain to more than one constructor - if you have one constructor taking just a `Foo`, one constructor taking just a `Bar`, and one constructor taking both, my approach works - the other doesn't, as you wouldn't be able to call *both* of the "half"-constructors from the "full" constructor.

Comment: Note that I view the `BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z)` as the more *general* constructor, as it allows *any* sort of initialization. The `BigBlock(Thing)` constructor is a more *specific* constructor as it *only* allows you to initialize with the default values for x, y and z.

Answer (score 3):

Just reuse your current constructor. Let every other constructor call the one that initialises all required values.

```
BigBlock(Thing myThing){
    parentThing = myThing;
    lengthUnit = parentThing.getPreferredUnits(0);
    labCoordinateSystem = parentThing.getCoordinateSystem();

}

BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z){
    this(myThing);
    // more code involving x, y, z
}
```

If `x`,`y` and `z` need to be part of the initalization, `BigBlock(Thing myThing)` should call `BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z)` with default values.

Answer (score 2):

No - you can call other constructors from a constructor using this.

```
BigBlock(Thing myThing) {
  this(myThing,0,0,0); // Pass default values for other constructors
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As almost always, the answer to 'which is the proper/best way to...' is "depends".

If the logic behind `Initialize` is specifically coupled to object creation, and `Thing` is common in all creation aspects, you could model that by inserting that behavior on the simplest constructor, and using it in every other one. That would centralize this usage of the initialisation behavior in only one place.

```
BigBlock(Thing myThing){
    parentThing= myThing;
    Initialize();
}

BigBlock(Thing myThing, double x, double y, double z){
    this(myThing);
    // more code involving x, y, z
}
```

In other circumstances, it may be useful to have `Initialize` as a separate method. For instance, if `initialize` does some reusable logic, llike a "reset" on the object you may call in a moment different than object creation.